# English Passive Future

Tags: grammar, passive-voice, future-tense

Active form: i won't finish it tomorrow. (I think it should: i m not finishing it tomorrow.)

Which is correct?

Passive:
1. It isn't being finished tomorrow.
2. It won't be finished tomorrow.

Comment: Are you asking about *finish* having multiple meanings, e.g. the *finish* on a car vs *finish* = complete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Active:

I think both can be correct

I would use the first one if I was expecting to work on it and knew it would not be complete, however it's not very clear whether you intend to work on it on not.

I would use the second one if I wasn't expecting to work on it at all.

Passive :

1  This time to me that says the activity of trying to achieve completeness is not been undertaken tomorrow

2  This says to me that it will be completed tomorrow and is somewhat open on whether you intend to work on it on not.